# how to pass a value to its parameter (default parameters)

Tags: c++, parameter-passing, default-parameters

I'm really confused because I can't describe my question well, but I'm sure that many of you will understand me.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void display(int n = 1, char c = '*');

int main()
{
    display();
    display(5);
    display('$');
    return 0;
}

void display(int n, char c)
{
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
        cout << c;
    cout << endl;
}
```

At `display('$')`, I want to pass this `char` to its parameter `c` and use `n` with its default value, which is 1.  Can anyone tell me how to do this properly?

Comment: Why not write another `display(char c = '*')` function to handle that case?

Comment: @tadman I'm not sure if the behaviour would be implementation defined or not but that would make it ambiguous as to which function to call, as `char` can be promoted to `int`.

Comment: @SchwiftyMcSchwifulface `char` is a better match for `char` than `int` is.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I guess, but which function would be called when the args are omitted?

Comment: @SchwiftyMcSchwifulface Than it's ambiguous and won't compile.

Comment: I would rather design the function as `void display(char c = '*', int n = 1)` than yours.  For example, if you just want to display one 'W', you can write `display('W')`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't as is.  When you call a function the parameters get matched from left to right in order.  That means `display('$');` will give `'$'` to `n` instead of `c`.

What you can do though, at least in this case, is overload the function to do what you want.  With

```
void display(int n, char c);
void display(int n);
void display(char c);
void display();
```

You can have the `void`, `int` and `char` overload call the main function and hide the fact that your filling in the "blanks".  That looks like

```
void display(int n)
{
    display(n, '*');
}

void display(char c)
{
    display(1, c);
}

void display()
{
    display(1, '*');
}
```

The down side here is your repeating the default values.  That makes this brittle as a change of the default values requires you to change it in multiple places.

Comment: I would implement `display()` as calling `display(1)` instead, so the default `'*'` char is specified in only one place. Or as calling `display('*')` so the default `1` is specified in only one place. If you want both defaults specified in one place, use global definitions: `const int def_n = 1; const char def_c = '*'; void display(int n) { display(n, def_c); } void display(char c) { display(def_n, c); } void display() { display(def_n, def_c); }`

Answer (score 2):

Default parameters can only be left out starting from the right. Thus your function

```
void display(int n = 1, char c = '*');
```

can only be called as

```
display();        // same as   display(1,'*');
display(5);       // same as   display(5,'*');
display(5,'a');
```

There are several ways to deal with this. The easiest in this case (as pointed out in a comment by tadman) would be to provide an overload that simply calls the original function

```
void display(char c) { display(1,c); }
```

You just have to take care that each overload has a different signature, eg you cannot have

```
void display(char c = '*') { display(1,c); }
```

because then a call `display()` would be ambiguous.
If there are more parameters it can make sense to declare a struct

```
struct Params {
    int n;
    char c;
    Params() : n(1),c('*') {}
};
```

This scales better with more parameters, because defaults can be used or not in any order:

```
Params p;
p.c = 'a';
display(p);
```

Answer (score 0):

I also found an another way, which is function redefinition.

Instead of

```
void display(int n = 1, char c = '*') {}
```

I could replace it with

```
void display(char c = '*', int n = 1) {}
```

But function overloading is better, because it will work on all conditions.